# Regular Expression for first two characters

Tags: regex

I need to match records starting with a certain character followed by subset of certain set of characters. After first two characters any character digit is allowed e.g.
in following dataset

```
man 
mbn
mcn
mdn
aan
adn
```

I need to extract words starting from m and followed by a-c. So only first 3 records should match.

Comment: Have you already tried anything? Or just think that someone will give you complete solution and you don't have to show any effort?

Comment: @Marcin I understand this forum is to raise question only after certain effort has been made.

Comment: Yes, you should show what you've tried. This way you'll not only get an answer but also learn what mistakes you've made which will make you a better programmer.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the lessons on programming but that doesn't solve my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this should work for you

```
^m[a-c]\w+$
```

Answer (score 0):

m[a-c] does what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

What language?  Perl, c#, python?  They're similar but here's a regex from c#:

> m[a-c]\w+

I'd also recommend that you take a look at [Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/) if you're building c# based regex strings. It works for other languages with the exception of .NET features.